# Scanner returning no line found

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am getting a "No line found" exception when I run this. This is the only method in my project that gives me this error. Every other method uses the same code and parameters, but none of them encounter this error.

The method in question is `findLargestPalindrome()`

**Exception**:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at cs1410.TestClass.findLongestPalindrome(TestClass.java:51)
    at cs1410.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:12)


import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class TestClass 
{
    static Scanner test = new Scanner("Hello world! This is my program.");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(findLongestPalindrome(test));
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String s)
    {
        if(s.length() == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        int stringLength = s.length() -1;

        if(stringLength == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
        {
            if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(stringLength))
            {
                stringLength--;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static String findLongestPalindrome(Scanner s)
    {
        int pLength = 0;
        String largestPalindrome = "";
        String currentToken;

        if(s.nextLine().length() > 0)
        {
            String input = s.nextLine();
            StringTokenizer inputTokens = new StringTokenizer(input);

            while(inputTokens.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                currentToken = inputTokens.nextToken();

                if(isPalindrome(currentToken) == true)
                {
                    if(currentToken.length() > pLength)
                    {
                        pLength = currentToken.length();
                        largestPalindrome = currentToken;
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
        return largestPalindrome;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your exception with complete stack trace.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
 at cs1410.TestClass.findLongestPalindrome(TestClass.java:51)
 at cs1410.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:12)

Comment: @Noremachi please add this to your post, and what method you are talking about?

Comment: findLongestPalindrom()

Comment: @Noremachi I bet you should use hasNextLine() . plz check it

Answer (score 2):

When you access the `Scanner` in `findLongestPalindrom()` you only have one line in the `Scanner` ("Hello world! This is my program.") and you are trying to read two lines (you discard the first line),

```
if(s.nextLine().length() > 0) // <-- reads the line and advances
{
    String input = s.nextLine(); // <-- there isn't another line.
```

should be something like

```
String input = s.nextLine();
if (!input.isEmpty()) {
  // ...
```

or

```
String input = s.nextLine();
if (input.length() > 0) {
  // ...
```

Every time you call [`Scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) you consume the line.